# DateTimePicker: the box goes back to it's original date?

Tags: vb.net, basic

Hey guys so im doing a program for a zodiac finder on vb,The program works and all but  my problem is that everytime I run it the DateTimePickerBox goes back to the current date instead of the date I have entered.

Here's my unfinished code;

Public Class HoroscopeSign

```
Private Sub HoroscopeSign_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    'DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    txtDOB.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short

End Sub

Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim DOB As Date = txtDOB.Value
    txtDOB.Text = Process(DOB)
End Sub
Public Function Process(dateOfBirth As Date) As String
    Dim sign As String
    Dim info As String
    Dim BirthYear As Integer = dateOfBirth.Year
    Dim BirthMonth As Integer = dateOfBirth.Month
    Dim BirthDay As Integer = dateOfBirth.Day


    If txtDOB.Value >= New Date(BirthYear, 1, 20) And txtDOB.Value <= New Date(BirthYear, 2, 18) Then
        PBHoroscope.Load("E:\Aquarius.jpg")
        sign = "Aquarius"
        info = ""
    Else txtDOB.Value >= New Date(BirthYear, 2, 19) And txtDOB.Value <= New Date(BirthYear, 3, 20) Then
        PBHoroscope.Load("E:\Pisces.jpg")
        sign = "Pisces"


    lblSign.Text = sign
    lblDescription.Text = info

End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Dim a As Integer
    a = MsgBox("Do you want to exit this application", vbYesNo, "Exit Application")
    If a = vbYes Then
        MsgBox("Thank you for using this application", vbOKOnly, "Exit Application")
        End
    Else
        Me.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Private Sub txtDOB_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDOB.ValueChanged
        Dim DOB As Date = txtDOB.Value
        DOB = txtDOB.Value
End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have declared your function `Process` to return a string, but you don't return anything from that function. The problem then arises when you try to assign the return value of that function to the `txtDOB.Text` property. You don't return anything and so the `txtDOB` resets itself to the current date

You should decide what string (in a date format) you want to return or better change your `Process` function to return a `DateTime` and assign that value to `txtDOB.Value` property. Or just change these lines to

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    ' REMOVE THIS LINE Dim DOB As Date = txtDOB.Value
    ' REMOVE THIS LINE txtDOB.Text = Process(DOB)
     Process(txtDOB.Value)
End Sub
```